# AWK: Extract string between two different patterns

Tags: regex, bash, awk, delimiter

I need to extract a string contained in a column of my csv.

My file is like this:

```
col1;col2;col3;cleavage=10-11;
col1;col2;col3;cleavage=1-2;
col1;col2;col3;cleavage=100-101;
col1;col2;col3;none;
```

So, the delimiter of my file is ";" but in column 4 I want to extract the string between "cleavage=" and a "-". What I did was to print the 2 chars after "cleavage=", but it's not always 2 chars.

I did it this way:

```
awk -F "\"*;\"*" '{if (match($4,"cleavage=")) print $1";"$2";"$3";"substr($4,RSTART+9,2); else print $1";"$2";"$3";0"}' file
```

I figured out that the following should be the correct command, but how should I integrate it in the previous one?

```
awk "/Pattern1/,/Pattern2/ { print }" inputFile
```

Thanks for help! :)

EDIT:
My actual output is

```
col1;col2;col3;10;
col1;col2;col3;1-;
col1;col2;col3;10;
col1;col2;col3;0;
```

But what I would like is:

```
col1;col2;col3;10;
col1;col2;col3;1;
col1;col2;col3;100;
col1;col2;col3;0;
```

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: What are those escaped quotes in the field separator for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this awk with multiple delimiters as field separator:

```
awk -F '[;=-]' -v OFS=';' '{print $1, $2, $3, ($4 == "cleavage") ? $5 : 0, ""}' file
col1;col2;col3;10;
col1;col2;col3;1;
col1;col2;col3;100;
col1;col2;col3;0;
```

**EDIT:** In case `-` or `=` can be present in fields before `$4` then you can use:

```
awk -F ';' -v OFS=';' '{split($4, a, /[=-]/);
           print $1, $2, $3, (a[1] == "cleavage") ? a[2] : 0, ""}' file
col1;col2;col3;10;
col1;col2;col3;1;
col1;col2;col3;100;
col1;col2;col3;0;
```

Comment: this is clever, but if a `- or =` exists in column `1-3`, it will fail. otherwise it is a good answer.

Comment: Good point @Kent, I have added another alternative for that case in my answer.

Comment: Great! I tried most of them but I'd say this is the best answer. It's easy and I easily integrated in my command (which was much longer). Also the others are great answers, but for my case I think this was the best one.

Answer (score 1):

Unclear of the exact format but this works for your example and will work if = and - are in other fields.

GNU awk (for match 3rd arg)

```
awk '{match($0,/(.*);[^-0-9]*([0-9]*)[^;]*;$/,a);print a[1]";"+a[2]";"}' file

col1;col2;col3;10;
col1;col2;col3;1;
col1;col2;col3;100;
col1;col2;col3;0;
```

or sed

```
sed 's/;[^-0-9]*\([0-9]\{1,\}\)[^;]*;$/;\1;/;t;s/[^;]*;$/0;/' file
```

Answer (score 0):

I come up with this one liner:

```
 awk -F';' -v OFS=";" '{sub(/cleavage=/,"",$(NF-1));
                        sub(/-.*/,"",$(NF-1));$(NF-1)+=0}7' file
```

it gives

```
col1;col2;col3;10;
col1;col2;col3;1;
col1;col2;col3;100;
col1;col2;col3;0;
```